# What is the best algorithm for bezier path clipping

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry

I know two common algorithms by Greiner-Hormann and Vatti. They work with polygons. I want to implement boolean operations on bezier paths. I want to extend these algorithms to work with bezier paths. But this is numerical problem. What is the best way to bezier path clipping? ( and what is the best modification of Greiner-Hormann algorithm for arbitrary polygons (with self intersections) )

Comment: I know about the articles by Andy Finnell. But this way is not good

Comment: Bezier curves of which degree ? 2 or 3 ? What kind of clipping are you interested in ? Vertical and horizontal ? At a specific point on the curve ?

Comment: I am intersting cubic bezier curves. Clipping by arbitrary bezier paths

Comment: You want to clip one bezier against another? That sounds like a really gnarly math problem to me.

Comment: I want to clip sequences of bezier curves by another sequences of bezier curves

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggested algorithm.

1. use the four control points to determine a polygon enclosing the bezier curve.
2. test polygon overlapping to see if two bezier curves may have an intersection point. If not overlapping, we are done, no clipping required.
3. if polygon overlap, split the two bezier curve in two using one casteljau iteration. Stop the recursion if the size of the bezier curve is too small regarding the required precision. Otherwise resume recursively with step 2.

In the process of dividing the bezier curve, keep track of where you are (value t) so that you can easily determine the 4 control point of the clipped bezier curve.

Note that at some point a bezier curve may be approximated to a straight line. In this case the overlapping test and splitting will be faster.

With this process you should end with a bezier curve cut in pieces by the clipping bezier curve. You still need to determine which piece is on which side of the clipping.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. I want to realize boolean operations on bezier paths. You give me algorithm of finding intersections of bezier curves

Comment: I want to realize idea from polygon clipping problem of Vatti and Greiner-Hormann

Comment: Could you please clarify "Boolean operations" ? What is the relation with clipping ?

Comment: I take this term from above articles.

Comment: Polygon clipping problem

Comment: Ref: http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/clipping/ So you have to find intersection points. Another solution is to approximate the beziers curves to polygons using the casteljau decomposition. You stop recursion when the four control points are nearly aligned. You then use polygon clipping.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to use bezier curves (no polygons). I want to use complete algorithm for arbitrary bezier paths. ( your link contains the adapted algorithm of Greiner-Hormann for polygon - it is not complete algorithm - it does not handle self - intersection polygons)

Comment: I gave you the algorithm to find intersection point between two bezier curves. To find self intersection point, split bezier curve in two and apply algorithm using both half. There can only be one self intersection point in a cubic bezier curve. This is the first half of the solution. The other half is to select the bezier segments that make the clipped bezier sequence. This is similar to the polygon clipping.

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct. It does not handle some degenerate cases. (self intersection for example, edge overlapping)

Comment: Self intersection is explained on the comment above. Overlapping edge is indeed not handled. This is not as trivial as for polygons. By approximating the bezier curve with a polyline you can fall back on the trivial case. This is how they do it in Adobe Illustrator. They convert the bezier curve into a sequence of lines. They use casteljau recursively until the four control points allignement is goog enough for the required precision. They use fixed point arithmetic for fast processing.

Comment: I tried implement. But Your algorithm is really bad. It cannot to handle touching points. He does not contain some words about right output topology.

Comment: I think that the best way is to convert bezier path into polygon, perform boolean operations and convert output to bezier curves